# How to know the keep alive interval needed for most router?

Tags: connection, router, intervals, nat, keep-alive

Most devices nowadays are behind NAT. When we make connection to server, router will create mapping for this connection and keep this mapping alive for some time. In order to keep this mapping, we have to actively send keep alive packet periodically.

How to know the keep alive interval needed? Is this interval different among protocols (UDP, TCP, ...)? Are there any documents ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this paper [TCP Wake-Up](http://www.pasieronen.com/publications/NRCTR2008002.pdf) which gives a general answer

```
The connection state timeout values vary from product to 
product, but typical values are 30…180 seconds for UDP and 
30…60 minutes for TCP [8]. This implies that applications 
using UDP need to send keep-alive messages much more 
frequently than those based on TCP
```

Comment: That paper is outdated. 4.5 - 5 minutes is more correct value now.

Answer (score 1):

this varies quite a bit, but i have never met a standard ISP home router that held open TCP for more than 10m or one that held open UDP for more than 3m, so I wouldn't take the 4.5-5m advice at all.

it's worth considering that most WebSockets implementations use a 20s keep-alive, though this is done for both routers and web-server timeouts, so it may be more conservative than you truly need for a NAT keepalive.

i have used 60s in some mobile- and home-based UDP apps and gotten feedback about occasional failures. shifting to 30s saw none, shifting to 45s saw just a minimal number of re-connect failures.